# mule datamapper org.mule.module.management.agent.WrapperManagerAgent

Tags: mule

I can able datamapper get it done .but i run in anypointstudio I got below error

> org.mule.module.management.agent.WrapperManagerAgent:` This JVM hasn't
>   been launched by the wrapper, the agent will not run.

any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning that has nothing to do with DataMapper, but instead is related to how the JVM has been started (with or without the Tanuki Wrapper).

In any case, this will not affect your usage of DataMapper.